# How to reassign a variable and run through code again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with reassigning a variable and then having the code change appropriately. I'm making a price page where users say how many employees they have and they are charged $21 a month for person (when locking in for a year). 10 employees at $21 each per month comes to $2520 a year. The $21 is at the yearly rate, if a company wants to pay per month, the rate goes from $21 to $23. My code works well for the $21 a month for a yearly sign up but how can I add $2 to the data-price if the company wants to just pay monthly? By default, the "Yearly" button at $21 a month is selected but if users click the "Monthly" button, I want it to change to $23 and start doing the calculations with that amount. I think my logic may be wrong so any suggestions are appreciated. [Here](https://timelyapp.com/pricing/) is the link to the working site im trying to mimic for practice. Below is what I have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkout").on("input", ".quantity", function() {
    var price = +$(".price").data("price");
    var quantity = +$(this).val();
    $("#total").text("$" + price * quantity);
  })

  var $buttonPlus = $('.increase-btn');
  var $buttonMin = $('.decrease-btn');
  var $quantity = $('.quantity');
  
  /*For plus and minus buttons*/
  $buttonPlus.click(function() {
    $quantity.val(parseInt($quantity.val()) + 1).trigger('input');
  });
  
  $buttonMin.click(function() {
    $quantity.val(Math.max(parseInt($quantity.val()) - 1, 0)).trigger('input');
  });
})
```

```css
.btnHover:hover {
 background-color:#17a2b8;
    color:white;
}
.priceTitle {
 font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #6bde9f;
    text-align: center;
}
.pricing {
 font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #6bde9f;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<!--Yearly/Monthly Buttons-->
 <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
   <center><div class="btn-group">
     <button style="font-weight:bold;" id="yearly" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Billed Yearly</button>
     <button type="button" id="monthlyBtn" class="btn btnHover">Billed Monthly</button>
   </div></center>
 </div> 
    <br>
<!--Calculation section-->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 checkout">
  <div style="margin-bottom:-25px;">
    <p class="price priceTitle" data-price="21">COMPANY</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="padding-left:100px;">
    <div class="col-6" style="height:50px;">
      <p class="total pricing" style="float:right; margin-right:-15px;"><span id="total">$21</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="height:90px;">
      <p style="font-size:12px; margin-top:40px; margin-left:-12px;">per<br> month</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <center><div>
    <p style="font-size:12px; margin-bottom:5px;">People on your team</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn decrease-btn">-</button>  
    <input style="width:70px; text-align:center; padding-bottom:5px" type="text" class="rounded quantity" value="1"></input> 
    <button type="button" class="btn increase-btn">+</button>   
  </div></center>    
</div>
```

Comment: The issue I am seeing is that the Monthly/Yearly buttons don't have any click event associated with them so they literally do nothing when you click on them.

Comment: @MattE You are definitely correct. Im still trying to learn how to reference buttons correctly with javascript, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move calculation logic to separate function. And call it whenever you need recalculation.

Your logic went right way. Data-attributes are nice here. You can store there some meta-data on buttons like "Billed monthly", so that when you handle click you can get data from element and recalculate with updated data.

I've updated your fiddle with handling type buttons and separated recalculation logic

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var price = 21;
  var $buttonPlus = $('.increase-btn');
  var $buttonMin = $('.decrease-btn');
  var $quantity = $('.quantity');
  var $paymentType = $('.payment-type');
  var $checkout = $(".checkout");
  
  $checkout.on("input", ".quantity", function() {
    recalc();
  })

  
  /*For plus and minus buttons*/
  $buttonPlus.click(function() {
    $quantity.val(parseInt($quantity.val()) + 1).trigger('input');
    recalc();
  });
  
  $buttonMin.click(function() {
    $quantity.val(Math.max(parseInt($quantity.val()) - 1, 0));
    recalc();
  });
  
  $paymentType.click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    price = $btn.data('price');
    $('#period').text($btn.data('period'));
    $paymentType.removeClass('btn-info');
    $btn.addClass('btnHover');
    recalc();
  });
  
  function recalc() {
    var quantity = +$quantity.val();
    $("#total").text("$" + price * quantity);
  }
  
  
})
```

```css
.btnHover:hover {
 background-color:#17a2b8;
    color:white;
}
.priceTitle {
 font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #6bde9f;
    text-align: center;
}
.pricing {
 font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #6bde9f;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--Yearly/Monthly Buttons-->
 <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
   <center><div class="btn-group">
     <button style="font-weight:bold;" id="yearly" type="button" class="btn btn-info payment-type" data-price="21" data-type="year">Billed Yearly</button>
     <button type="button" id="monthlyBtn" class="btn btnHover payment-type" data-price="23" data-type="month">Billed Monthly</button>
   </div></center>
 </div> 
    <br>
<!--Calculation section-->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 checkout">
  <div style="margin-bottom:-25px;">
    <p class="price priceTitle" data-price="21">COMPANY</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="padding-left:100px;">
    <div class="col-6" style="height:50px;">
      <p class="total pricing" style="float:right; margin-right:-15px;"><span id="total">$21</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="height:90px;">
      <p style="font-size:12px; margin-top:40px; margin-left:-12px;">per<br> <span id="period">month</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <center><div>
    <p style="font-size:12px; margin-bottom:5px;">People on your team</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn decrease-btn">-</button>  
    <input style="width:70px; text-align:center; padding-bottom:5px" type="text" class="rounded quantity" value="1"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn increase-btn">+</button>   
  </div></center>    
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Im going to study up on your code cause it looks way better than what I was trying to come up with!